Is it possible to disable manual docker container restarts?
We have a few containers in production which occasionally have issues and need to be restarted. However, there are a few additional steps we need to take when doing restarts due to service dependencies and how the service works, so we use Jenkins jobs to handle rebooting the service. Consequently, going in and using the docker restart syntax will leave the service in a bad state.
Not all of our ops team knows this though, as they're constantly onboarding and replacing team members. I would love to disable the docker restart syntax and if possible add a friendly "This container doesn't allow restarts, please contact devs" kind of message, but all my searches just turn up results with how to disable auto-restart, which is a different problem

One possibility is to shadow the docker command by writing a script.
For example, you could make a script like this:
/usr/local/bin/custom-docker
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Checking for "docker restart"
if [[ $1 == "restart" ]]; then
  echo "Please do not run the command 'docker restart' without contacting the devs."
  exit 1
fi

# Otherwise, pass all arguments to the real Docker command
exec /usr/bin/docker "$@"

Set execute permissions
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/custom-docker

Then alias to docker in your .profile file or an .<shell>rc file
alias docker='/usr/local/bin/custom-docker'

Now docker restart prints out the error message but everything else works as before.

But remember that docker restart is just a shortcut for docker container restart. This full version will still work, as will docker -D restart or docker -- restart. So this has very limited impact to someone who is willing to do harm, but will surely work in many contexts...

Yeah, you're right. And now that I re-read the question, OP wanted to disable manual restarts for just some containers, not necessarily all of them.

But that's easily done with checking $2 for the "correct" value... Since I don't see any other way, I would also resort to though an alias at it, so who am I to judge

@jolammi We only run one service container per host, so it wouldn't be a problem to disable them for all docker restart commands (on that host). I guess the only issues would be the ones boppy suggested. Maybe that's the way to go, short of trying to submit a docker feature request lol

Of course it's possible to include all possible variations of the docker restart command into the shadowing alias, but even then a person that really wants to restart a container can just do /usr/bin/docker restart.

@jolammi I don't think anyone is doing it maliciously, I just think the normal reaction to "docker container in bad state" is "restart docker container" so as long as we can send them a little message that says "hey don't do this" then worst case, we're back where we started. Anyway, I'm gonna accept your answer and see if the rest of the devs on my team are interested. Thanks for the help guys
